# Return unique keys from JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm hoping my question is using the correct terminology...

Can someone explain to me how I can perform the following:

If I have an array consisting of:

> Object { id=1498, brandName="Booths", quality="Standard"}
>   Object { id=1499, brandName="Booths", quality="Standard"}

How can I iterate throughout that array and return another array of distinct 'keys'?

Ultimately I want an array which would return something like:

[id,brandName,quality] (but the original array is going to return different keys at different times.

Have I made sense?

Comment: You may simply use `for (var key in obj) { ... }`. Or is there a problem? If so, show us your code.

Comment: No, have tried that, it just returns the first key, I need it pumped to an array with unique keys.

Comment: What defines unique? Comparing those objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys`:

```
var a1 = [{ id:1498, brandName:"Booths", quality:"Standard"}, 
          { id:1499, brandName:"Booths", quality:"Standard"}],
    a1Keys = a1.map(function(a){return Object.keys(a);});
//a1Keys now:
[['id','brandName','quality'],['id','brandName','quality']]
```

The `keys` method is described [@MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), including a shim for older browsers

Comment: That's almost exactly what I want, returns the names exactly as wanted, just need to now return only one array of unique keys rather than 1500 of them.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = {"a": 1, "b": "t" };
var keys = new Array();
for(var o in a){
    keys.push(o);
}
console.log(keys)
```